# Google play store app submission rules

Tags: android, google-play

I want to submit an app in which there are some services that needs to be run in the background like what'sapp or facebook.Does google playstore will easily allow me to do so?Is there any process?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, services are allowed. You can read [policy here](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't check app submissions as rigorously as Apple does. Running something in the background is completely fine. There are some rules however and you can read about them [**here**](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html).

You can also read through [**this**](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html). It should cover everything you need to know about preparing an app for release and how to release it. You can find a release checklist [**here**](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Apps with services are allowed to be distributed via playstore.**

Before you publish your apps on Google Play and distribute them to users, you need to get the apps ready, test them, and prepare your promotional materials.

**Follow the link below to prepare your checklist :** 
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

**Also have a look at Google Play Developer policies below :** 

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Hope this Helps!